# Swift UItableView Custom cell programmatically (documentation)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I've been trying to find some documentation/tutorial/examples. On how to do an advanced tableview in swift. But I've come up empty besides the endless storyboard tutorials.

I'm doing this without storyboards and nibs. And I haven't been able to find any documentation beyond's Apple's /poorly/ explained library.

Rather than trying to explain exactly what I'm looking for, I'll simply show an image of the design below.

[image]

Right now, I'm obviously not asking you guys to create this for me. I'm simply hoping you can send me a link to some documentation/tutorial. That explains how to make cells different? and how you position elements within a cell programmatically.

I've been searching for cell constraints, but I can't find any?

I looked into prototype cells too, but all I could find was storyboard related.

I'm hoping you guys could show me an example of something similar, some documentation / tutorial.

Another important thing. Any documentation I did find that wasn't using storyboards. All used a tableViewController.

I'm using a UIViewController, with a UITableView. Not a tableViewController, which seems to make a huge difference on how it works.

Right now I'm just trying to get a prototype working.

here's my data below:

```
var objects = NSMutableArray()
var dataArray = [   ["stockName":"CTC Media Inc.","action":"sell","stockPrice":12.44],
                    ["stockName":"Transglobal Energy","action":"buy","stockPrice":39.40],
                    ["stockName":"NU Skin Enterprises","action":"buy","stockPrice":4.18]
                ]
```

I've only been able to grab and display one piece of data from it though.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return self.stocks.count
    return dataArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let object = dataArray[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    cell.textLabel?.text = object["stockName"] as? String

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

But I'm still clueless on how I position this data, or add more to it. Such as the UIView on the right with a specific background color. Centering a UILabel within that UIView, adding a UIView on the left with padding, custom spacing between cells. Etc. etc.

Any help, links to documentation, suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I tried adding constraints inside the cell with. "cell.view.addConstraints("

But of course it throws an error saying "UITableViewCell does not have a member named view".

So as for how to do constraints inside cells, I'm still blank :(

EDIT 2 - progress:

I managed to get a UIView to show up using the following code:

```
        testView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.addSubview(testView)

    var viewsDictionary = [ "testView":testView]
    cell.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|-50-[testView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    cell.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|[testView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```

However, for some reason, it only shows up in the last cell, not all cells?

Comment: You need to create a view for the price container. Based on the action for each row you can have a `if... else...` to decide on the background image. For more on how to add constraints programmatically you can check this tutorial. http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/

Comment: Thanks for the comment!. I have created all of the objects I need, however I have no way to put them inside these cells. I know how constraints work. But I don't have any idea, how to add constraints to items inside a cell? Does the tableview create a cell object for me?, What decides where the cell label is placed? How do I add these objects to my cell.

Comment: did you see [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)? did you try to find much enough ?

Comment: hello Huy Nghia, thanks for the comment! Yeah I saw that tutorial, but like the rest I could find, it's based on storyboards, the design of the cell is done with a prototype cell in storyboard and not programatically :(

Comment: programatically ? basicly is you create view on your code instead drag drop in storyboard ? so.... what is your problem ?

Comment: if you read my last edit, I managed to get a UIView to show up, but it only shows up in the last cell. Not in all cells.

Comment: your prolem is you only use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier but never create cell so how can tablview reuse cell for you ??????

Comment: after several hours, I finally managed to find 1 piece of great documentation that explains doing this programatically. Hopefully this helps anyone else struggling with the same issue. https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Table-View-Guide

Comment: If you're doing this all in code, then you should create a subclass of UITableViewCell, and add all your subviews (with constraints) there. In the controller, register the class, and in cellForRowAtIndexPath cast the cell to whatever your custom class is.

Comment: @HuyNghia, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier does create a cell if need be, that's what that method does. It creates a cell if there isn't one, and reuses one if there is one to reuse.

Comment: [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered.If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil. In this case he use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:  only so that it return nil

Comment: While reading this question I smiled, I feel you bro! since I am currently learning swift and entering that headache, and there is no hate I can express more to this storyboard jumbo mumbo, the poor documentation, the lack of understanding in these idiotic tutorials, as if all the watchers don't know what class and object is! and all these limitation and apple "standards" to design.. what happened to creativity!! and what with these ridiculous silly long methods names.. seriously apple!!! 
I thank God I come from windows/linux/web background, where programing is serious!

Comment: Please have look on Brian Voong's tutorial on youtube. He always used to code without storyboard.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[image]

I just played little bit. Even though all the colors/fonts are not quite right, this will give you good starting point. Hope it helps you.

```
class Stock {
var name: String?
var action: String?
var price: String?
init(stockData: [String: AnyObject]) {
    if let n = stockData["stockName"] as? String {
        name = n
    }
    if let a = stockData["action"] as? String {
        action = a
    }
    if let p = stockData["stockPrice"] as? Float {
        price = NSString(format: "%.2f", p)
    }
}

var backgroundColor: UIColor {
    if action == "sell" {
        return UIColor.greenColor()
    }
    return UIColor.blueColor()
}

var typeColor: UIColor {
    if action == "sell" {
        return UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    return UIColor.purpleColor()
}

var priceLabelColor: UIColor {
    if action == "sell" {
        return UIColor.redColor()
    }
    return UIColor.greenColor()
}
}


class StockCell: UITableViewCell {

let padding: CGFloat = 5
var background: UIView!
var typeLabel: UILabel!
var nameLabel: UILabel!
var priceLabel: UILabel!

var stock: Stock? {
    didSet {
        if let s = stock {
            background.backgroundColor = s.backgroundColor
            priceLabel.text = s.price
            priceLabel.backgroundColor = s.priceLabelColor
            typeLabel.text = s.action
            typeLabel.backgroundColor = s.typeColor
            nameLabel.text = s.name
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    selectionStyle = .None

    background = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    background.alpha = 0.6
    contentView.addSubview(background)

    nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    nameLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)

    typeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    typeLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    typeLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    contentView.addSubview(typeLabel)

    priceLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    priceLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    priceLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    contentView.addSubview(priceLabel)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    background.frame = CGRectMake(0, padding, frame.width, frame.height - 2 * padding)
    typeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(padding, (frame.height - 25)/2, 40, 25)
    priceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(frame.width - 100, padding, 100, frame.height - 2 * padding)
    nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(typeLabel.frame) + 10, 0, frame.width - priceLabel.frame.width - (CGRectGetMaxX(typeLabel.frame) + 10), frame.height)
}
}
```

in your view controller

```
var stocks: [Stock] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    for stockData in dataArray {
        var stock = Stock(stockData: stockData)
        stocks.append(stock)
    }


    tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .Grouped)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    tableView.registerClass(StockCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(StockCell))
    view.addSubview(tableView)
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stocks.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( NSStringFromClass(StockCell), forIndexPath: indexPath) as StockCell
    cell.stock = stocks[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
```

Custom Cell

```
class StockCell: UITableViewCell {

let padding: CGFloat = 5
var background: UIView!
var typeLabel: UILabel!
var nameLabel: UILabel!
var priceLabel: UILabel!

var stock: Stock? {
    didSet {
        if let s = stock {
            background.backgroundColor = s.backgroundColor
            priceLabel.text = s.price
            priceLabel.backgroundColor = s.priceLabelColor
            typeLabel.text = s.action
            typeLabel.backgroundColor = s.typeColor
            nameLabel.text = s.name
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    selectionStyle = .None

    background = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    background.alpha = 0.6
    contentView.addSubview(background)

    nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    nameLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)

    typeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    typeLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    typeLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    contentView.addSubview(typeLabel)

    priceLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    priceLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    priceLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    contentView.addSubview(priceLabel)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    background.frame = CGRectMake(0, padding, frame.width, frame.height - 2 * padding)
    typeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(padding, (frame.height - 25)/2, 40, 25)
    priceLabel.frame = CGRectMake(frame.width - 100, padding, 100, frame.height - 2 * padding)
    nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(typeLabel.frame) + 10, 0, frame.width - priceLabel.frame.width - (CGRectGetMaxX(typeLabel.frame) + 10), frame.height)
}
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was just looking for a hint of documentation, or for someone to tell me that I could make a class for the cell. But yeah, perfect answer, thanks a million times! I did mine a bit diferent following the documentation in the answer below. But this is definitely the better answer.

Comment: @user100002 glad that it helped. I was lil bit rushed so that I forgot to add resetting all the cell subviews when those are reused. You just need to set all the labels' texts to nil and background colors to default colors (if you have them) in prepareForReuse.

Comment: @HMHero - Thank you so so much. This was a perfect and simple break down of a simple and straight-forward design pattern. Thanks for your time!