# Programmatically or XIB implementation of TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I'm attempting to build a demo app which looks very similar to the default iOS calendar app. I'm almost finished but am not entirely sure what the best practice is on applying custom cell on the TableView.

Looking at the screenshot (see below), the default app has a TableView of all the events on a given day. How should I go about applying that styling into my cell?

At the moment, I have this (basically called in my `viewDidAppear` method:

- Month title as a label which is defined in Storyboard
- Calendar package which I'm applied programmatically
- Default iOS Tableview which is also applied programmatically beneath this

Because the TableView is applied programmatically I'm not entirely sure where to go. Below is my code for the TableView:

```
let cellReuseIdentifier = "eventCell"
let offsetY = {% Some fancy calculation here to get offset pos %}
let height = {% Just as above but to determine remaining height %}

tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, offsetY, screenSize.width, height)
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

view.addSubview(tableView)
```

And the specific Data Source methods:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return selectedEvents.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier)!
      let event = selectedEvents[indexPath.row]

      // set the text from the data model
      cell.textLabel?.text = "\(event.startTime) - \(event.endTime) | \(event.summary)"

      return cell
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
  }
```

Any guidance would be appreciated :)

[image: iOS Calendar]

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
tableView.registerClass(CustomCellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellClasId")
```

And then :

```
internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellClassId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCellClass{
            // set up cell
            return cell
        }
}
```

Comment: @sukh this answer is how you use your custom cell class - whether it's implemented programmatically or xib is up to you but in my experience most people find xibs easier to design.

Comment: Thanks @andrew-mckinley and @bradkratky - For me to get this to work I had to remove the `registerClass` line - is this right? I can add further details if necessary...basically I created a new subclassed `UITableViewCell` with its corresponding XIB file. Changed the reuse identifier and amended the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to check if the cell is nil. If it is nil, I use the following line: `tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "RoomDetailTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "roomDetailCell")` and then basically dequeued the cell again

Comment: Okay think you can ignore my stupidness - I've found another duplicated StackOverflow post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999400/swift-uitableview-custom-cell-programatically-documentation - will just follow this :)